# Why sometimes swift static variable is initialized incorrectly when compile for optimize for speed

Tags: swift

I recently run into a problem that sometimes swift static variables are initialized incorrectly. This issue could be reproduced when compile for speed optimization(which is the default optimize level for release model in Xcode). See the codes below:

```swift
class MainView: UIView {
    static let someValue: Int = {
        print("some value init")
        return 1
    }()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var falseValue = false
    var falseValue2 = false
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if falseValue {
            print(MainView.someValue)
        }
        if falseValue2 {
            print(MainView.someValue)
        }
    }
}
```

For the code above, the `MainView.someValue` should not be initialized, but when compile in release model or optimize for speed(-o), the `some value init` will be printed, which means the `someValue` has been initialized. But none of the print in `if` statement is executed.

Why the compile do this optimization? And this will cause some logic error when `someValue`'s init block do some complex work.

Comment: Interesting, looks like SILOptimizer has a pass where it can hoist calls to static initialisers out of multiple blocks, even if those blocks may not be reachable during execution. Somewhat related bug report: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-181.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug reported as [SR-11494](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11494). Stored type properties are supposed to be lazily initialized on their first access. As per the [Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

However, in this case, when compiled with the optimization flag the stored Type property's initialization is called at compile-time.

**Bug Update (12/08/2020):**

This issue has been fixed in Swift 5.3

Comment: Aren't static variables lazy, though? Is this inconsistent behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug or the expected result of the SIL optimizer. filed a bug for the inconsistent behavior (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11494)